# Applet parameter contains back slash.

Tags: java, parameters, character-encoding, applet

When i define either one of the parameters below in a html page which starts the applet:

```
<param name=testParam value=test\\test> 
<param name=testParam value='test\\test'>
```

`applet.getParameter("testParam")` method returns value as "test\\test". In my logic it should return "test\test".(for value=test\test then method returns "test\test") How is this possible? is it something relating to the encoding or something that java handles when it gets output.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the value in quotes .. value="test\\test" ??

Comment: @Kal: yes i have tried and it is the same

Comment: What if you use only one slash?

Comment: @Evan Mulawski then it returns with one back slash in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Java** requires back-slashes to be escaped.  **HTML** does *not.*

#### E.G.

```
/* <applet
    code='TestParam'
    width='200'
    height='30'>
<param name='path' value='test\test'>
</applet> */
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestParam extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        JTextField output = new JTextField(getParameter("path"), 20);
        add(output);
        validate();
    }
}
```

#### Result

[image: Applet showing string]

Answer (score 3):

Your string is defined in html not in java. In html there is no need to escape backslashes hence why you are getting "test\test". If you need to have it with one slash, then define the string with one slash.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to escape a single backslash in HTML.

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/revsol.html